# Update View on Resume (Return to view after selecting an item from list view)

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a view that displays some data for a selected city using a web service, it works fine if I have already selected a city. View is populated with data using onCreateView as its inherits from Fragment.

But, user can select a new city, by going to next view. As the user selects the city and press back button, now how can I update the view ?

Edit:
View1: Displays data if a city is already selected.
User goes from view1 to view 2
View2:Select a city from list view (On list item click, city is saved and onBackPressed is called to move back to View1)
Now when View1 is is presented again, how to update view ?

Comment: please elaborate your question....

Answer (score 0):

**First way** - Create fragment transaction and replace fragment

**Second way** - Implement `setCity` method in your fragment and update view in this method.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `onResume` when returning to a view, and if the view needs to be updated.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
   // TODO: code here
}
```